# I'd like to create a CAGradientLayer Subclass/Utility class

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I've been programming in one way or another for 30+ years, but I'm new to Swift and iOS programming and working on my first app. I've worked out how to create a CAGradientLayer to show a gradient on screen, but I'd like to create a utility class/extension/subclass with some predefined gradients in it.

I am assuming I can do this by creating subclasses of CAGradientLayer with the properties pre-set at initialisation time, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax to do this. I guess I am missing some basic Swift requirements?

I've tried the following:

```
let greenBlueGradient = GreenBlueGradient.greenBlueGradient()

class GreenBlueGradient: CAGradientLayer {

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func greenBlueGradient() -> GreenBlueGradient {
        self.colors = [ UIColor.init( red: 0.05, green: 0.75, blue: 0.91, alpha: 1.0 ).CGColor, UIColor.init( red: 0.56, green: 0.93, blue: 0.56, alpha: 1.0 ).CGColor ]
        return self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" on the let line. What am I missing? Surely there is a more efficient way of doing this? I sort of have in my head that I will be able to create some sort of utility class/extension that will return a CAGradientLayer with the colors already set ready for me to set the frame and insert it into my view hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud add an extension of CAGradientLayer in other file for exemple :
in file "UIExtensionsCAGradientLayer.swift"

```
extension CAGradientLayer {
    func setupGreenBlurGradient(){
       self.colors = [UIColor.init( red: 0.05, 
                                    green: 0.75, 
                                    blue: 0.91, 
                                    alpha: 1.0).CGColor,
                      UIColor.init( red: 0.56, 
                                    green: 0.93, 
                                    blue: 0.56, 
                                    alpha: 1.0 ).CGColor ]
    }
}
```

Then in the file where you need the green blur gradient you do :

```
let greenGradientBlur = CAGradientLayer(layer : layer)
greenGradientBlur.setupGreenBlueGradient()
```

Comment: I had to add `return self` to the end of this function, but this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. Subclassing and setting the colors in init() required I implement a number of `required` functions in each and every subclass which lead to rapid code bloat.

Comment: i forgot to deleete the return in func declaration you dont event need a return :)

Comment: Note that `UIColor(red:...)` would work; you don't have to say `UIColor.init(red:...)`.

Comment: yes i know, I just used his method to init a color. I always use `UIColor(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The error message here is a bit misleading. ([File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about that. [Or fix it yourself](http://swift.org), if you're so inclined, now that Swift is open source.)

Your attempt to call `GreenBlueGradient.greenBlueGradient()` fails because you're calling an instance method as if it were a class method. *That call* would succeed if you'd declared `greenBlueGradient()` as a `class func`. However, that function's implementation relies on `self`.

What you probably want instead is to add your customization to `init`:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    self.colors = [
        UIColor(red: 0.05, green: 0.75, blue: 0.91, alpha: 1.0).CGColor,
        UIColor(red: 0.56, green: 0.93, blue: 0.56, alpha: 1.0).CGColor,
    ]
}
```

That way, a client can get your custom gradient just by constructing an instance:

```
let greenBlueGradient = GreenBlueGradient()
```

Pretty colors, by the way.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did this, but CAGradientLayer (or more likely CALayer) required I implement a number of `required` functions which lead to huge code bloat when overriding this more than once for different gradients. Using the function method suggested by @Coyote proved more elegant.